# ZIP files not being completely uploaded from C++ to PHP

Tags: c++

I have a C++ console application that uploads a zip archive to a php page. The upload is working for text and image files but does not work for zip files which I need.

I used the code given here: [Send file POST C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26895159/send-file-post-c)

I made changes to the C++ code and the final code is below.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"wininet.lib")
#define ERROR_OPEN_FILE       10
#define ERROR_MEMORY          11
#define ERROR_SIZE            12
#define ERROR_INTERNET_OPEN   13
#define ERROR_INTERNET_CONN   14
#define ERROR_INTERNET_REQ    15
#define ERROR_INTERNET_SEND   16

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 // Local variables
 static char *filename   = "hello.zip";   //Filename to be loaded
 static char *filepath   = "C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\hello.zip";   //Filename to be loaded
 static char *type       = "application/zip";
 static char boundary[]  = "--BOUNDARY---";            //Header boundary
 static char nameForm[]  = "file";     //Input form name
 static char iaddr[]     = "localhost";        //IP address
 static char url[]       = "/u.php";         //URL

 char hdrs[512]={'-'};                  //Headers
 char * buffer;                   //Buffer containing file + headers
 char * content;                  //Buffer containing file
 FILE * pFile;                    //File pointer
 long lSize;                      //File size
 size_t result;                   

 // Open file
 pFile = fopen ( filepath , "rb" );
 if (pFile==NULL) 
 {
     printf("ERROR_OPEN_FILE");
     getchar();
     return ERROR_OPEN_FILE;
 }
 printf("OPEN_FILE\n");

 // obtain file size:
 fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
 lSize = ftell (pFile);
 rewind (pFile);

 // allocate memory to contain the whole file:
 content = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*(lSize+1));
 if (content == NULL) 
 {
     printf("ERROR_MEMORY");
     getchar();
     return ERROR_OPEN_FILE;
 }
 printf("MEMORY_ALLOCATED\t \"%d\" \n",&lSize);
 // copy the file into the buffer:
 result = fread (content,1,lSize,pFile);
 if (result != lSize) 
 {
     printf("ERROR_SIZE");
     getchar();
     return ERROR_OPEN_FILE;
 }
 printf("SIZE_OK\n");

 content[lSize] = '\0';

 // terminate
 fclose (pFile);
 printf("FILE_CLOSE\n");
 //allocate memory to contain the whole file + HEADER
 buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize + 2048);

 //print header
 sprintf(hdrs,"Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=%s",boundary);
 sprintf(buffer,"%s\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%s\"; filename=\"%s\"\r\n",boundary,nameForm,filename);
 sprintf(buffer,"%sContent-Type: %s\r\n",buffer,type);
 sprintf(buffer,"%s\r\n%s",buffer,content);
 sprintf(buffer,"%s\r\n--%s--\r\n",buffer,boundary);

 printf("%s", buffer);

 //Open internet connection
 HINTERNET hSession = InternetOpen("WINDOWS",INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
 if(hSession==NULL) 
 {
     printf("ERROR_INTERNET_OPEN");
     getchar();
     return ERROR_OPEN_FILE;
 }
 printf("INTERNET_OPENED\n");

 HINTERNET hConnect = InternetConnect(hSession, iaddr,INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
 if(hConnect==NULL) 
 {
     printf("ERROR_INTERNET_CONN");
     getchar();
     return ERROR_INTERNET_CONN;
 }
 printf("INTERNET_CONNECTED\n");

 HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, (const char*)"POST",_T(url),NULL, NULL, NULL,INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 1);
 if(hRequest==NULL) 
  {
     printf("ERROR_INTERNET_REQ");
     getchar();

 }
 printf("INTERNET_REQ_OPEN\n");

 BOOL sent= HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, strlen(hdrs), buffer, strlen(buffer));

 if(!sent) 
 {
     printf("ERROR_INTERNET_SEND");
     getchar();
     return ERROR_INTERNET_CONN;
 }
 printf("INTERNET_SEND_OK\n");

 InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
 InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
 InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);

 getchar();
 return 0;
}
```

The C++ output returned is as follows:

```
OPEN_FILE
MEMORY_ALLOCATED         "2348964"
SIZE_OK
FILE_CLOSE
----BOUNDARY--
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="hello.zip"
Content-Type: application/zip

PK♥♦¶
----BOUNDARY--
INTERNET_OPENED
INTERNET_CONNECTED
INTERNET_REQ_OPEN
INTERNET_SEND_OK
```

It seems that the zip file is not completely read as only first 5 characters are being displayed (PK♥♦¶) instead of entire file. I have tried increasing the size of `hdrs` to accommodate entire contents, but does not work. The zip file is approximately 37KB in size. Please help as I am not much familiar with http requests in C++.

**EDIT:** Finally got it working after I came across a similar question: [how to send a zip file using wininet in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407755/how-to-send-a-zip-file-using-wininet-in-my-vc-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not related to http requests at all.

Basically what you ask is: why can't i handle binary data as string?

The answer is: because string functions (like printf, strlen) all stop parsing at the first null character they encounter, and binary files (like a zip file) do contain null characters.

So when sending the data, dont try to get the length of the data as a string:
`BOOL sent= HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, strlen(hdrs), buffer, strlen(buffer));`

instead use the length you already have in `lSize`

Comment: What alternate should I use?

Comment: Print it as hexadecimal, or just print the length. Why would you want to show the binary data anyway?

Comment: The zip file is not being uploaded completely. In the upload folder, the zip is only about 5 bytes instead of a 37KB archive.

Comment: and you are sure the problem is in the c++ code, not in the .php?

Comment: Ah, you make the same assumpting when trying to send the data as when trying to display it: binary data is *not* a string, so you cannot use strlen(). Updated my answer to also include this

Comment: Using `lSize` does not help either. The zip archive is same as before 5 bytes. Does sprintf too stops at null character? Would that be causing the problem?

Comment: yes, ALL functions handling strings stop at a null character.

Comment: Can you please suggest a method to overcome this issue?